# JSON object is not returned with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am beginning to play around with JSON, and I keep running into trouble that neither Google nor SO have helped me with.  I have a  very simple PHP script:

```
<?php

$email = $_REQUEST['email'];

if ( strpos($email,'@') !== false ) {
    $data = array('status' => 1 , 'msg' => 'Sent') ;
    echo json_encode( $data ) ;
} 

else {
    $data = array('status' => 0 , 'msg' => 'Failed to send') ;
    echo json_encode( $data ) ; 
}


?>
```

I have the following ajax call:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {
    $('div.load').html('<img src="images/load.gif" alt="Loading..." id="loading" />'); //EDIT

    //creation of variables to send
    var name = $('#name').val();
        email = $('#email').val();
        phone = $('#phone').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jason",

        data: {
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone
        },

        url: "test.php",

        success: function( data ) {

            $('.contact').append( data )

        }
    });

    return false; 

});
```

If the php gets called without JS (and the form doesn't contain a proper email address), then I get the following object (which is what I want!): {"status":0,"msg":"Failed to send"}

However, if submitting with JS (ajax), the JSON object never gets received.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that you mistyped the ajax datatype param (should be json instead of jason)

Comment: May not be an issue here, but don't you have a typo in `dataType`? I don't know any `jason`.

Comment: Are the PHP headers set to send JSON data?

Comment: also, are you sure you want to append the JSON object to `$(".contact")`, don't you want to do something with the object first?

Comment: @dotty:  I don't actually want to append the object.  But before I actually used the object, I wanted to make sure I'm properly receiving it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dataType: "jason",
```

Read:

```
dataType: "json",
```

;-)

Also, you have some semi colons where there should be commas:

```
var name = $('#name').val(),    // These two lines should be comma-terminated to
    email = $('#email').val(),  // make this a correct var declaration
    phone = $('#phone').val();
```

Comment: Haha, nice catch.  Is that the only bug that you see, because having fixed that, I still don't get the json object returned :(

Comment: @Amit What do you see when you `console.log(data);` in the `success` function? Also, try adding an `error` handler

Comment: Interesting! If I console.log(data), I do seem to get the proper object.  I wonder why it doesn't want to append it?

Comment: How do you want it to display? You can't really just append a non-DOM object to the DOM, it needs to be some form of string representation...

Comment: I see.  I wasn't aware a JSON object is non-DOM.  I apologize, I'm only now starting to play with this stuff (I'm super late to the game).  Everything seems to be working.  Thanks for catching the typos!

Comment: For example you could `$('.contact').append("<div>Status: "+data.status+"; Message: "+data.msg+"</div>");`